# J'ai pas faim vs. Je n'ai faim pas

Tags: négation

I was taught in a beginner college french course that any negation is of the form "ne *verb* pas", but I've stumbled across "J'ai pas faim" as a way to write "Je n'ai faim pas", and I was wondering if the former was more colloquial? If yes, then can it be used for other expressions, like for example "Je suis pas seul," instead of "Je ne suis pas seul"?

Comment: « Je n'ai faim pas » is wrong. It’s « Je n’ai pas faim » (the verb here is _avoir_)

Comment: Also note that for « Je ne sais pas » you’ll often hear « J’sais pas » which roughly prononces like « chépa » ;) Can be quite disturbing for a foreigner…

Comment: @Stéphane : "chépa" is equivalent to "dunno".

Answer (score 1):

"J'ai pas faim" is informal language, a shortened version of "Je n'ai pas faim". The *ne* is very oftenly removed in everyday common speaking (friends, family...).

Comment: I want to add that you may remove "ne" in an informal conversation, but never omit "pas".

Comment: To be more precise, using "je n'ai faim" never occurs in a normal conversation